# What is the best way to implement a web application with editable data grid in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, gridview

I need to implement an editable datagrid which allows to get and edit data from single table and joined tables as well. I use SQL Sqerver 2008 db and Linq to SQL.

Shall I use a ASP.NET GridView control or may be go for Silverlight? Are there any jQuery + AJAX frameworks for it?

What approach would you recommend?

Thank you.

Comment: take a look at http://odetocode.com/articles/218.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any one of the items you listed will work. Your question needs some more description as to what you want to accomplish.

If you want to accomplish an interactive grid that has flash like apperance then use Silverlight or depending on how interactive Jquery, if you want to have seamless integration with your database and no page reloads occur then use Jquery / AJAX.  The ASP.Net gridview alone will be your most limiting as it will create a page refresh but it will work great if your just showing the user their data and need them to update it accordingly.

I would recommend using Jquery / Ajax as I like the non refreshing and no page reloads jquery has to offer.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I will go for jQuery / Ajax using http://datatables.net/ and jeditable

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to achieve this, including Robert's solution of implementing an editing solution using jQuery.

If you're prepared to use a third party solution, Telerik make a particularly good set of controls for ASP.NET and AJAX, one of which is a grid.

Here's an [example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/alleditablecolumns/defaultcs.aspx) of one of their grid controls.  There's support for joining tables and edit on click.

There are many others on this page which would achieve the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, Telerik looks great, but it is a little bit expensive